# Using Abstract Class to Implement Interface

Tags: java, oop, interface

I have an interface. For the sake of this question, I'll simplify it to this:

```
interface EraseableColoredPencil {

  //This method seems appropriate for an interface;
  //The implementation will change with each class that implements this interface.
  void draw();

  //This method does not seem as appropriate;
  //The implementation of the erase method would be the same for all classes.
  void erase();
}
```

My question is: **According to OOP principles, what is the best way to express this?** An interface for both methods does not seem appropriate. Here are the options that I have come up with:

1. **List all methods, whether or not the implementation is the same, on the interface. Then use an abstract class for the shared erase() implementation.** This seems like be best solution to me, as an `EraseableColoredPencil` WILL need to implement `erase()` and this allows all classes to share the same implementation. I know this is possible, but my concern is whether or not it follows best practices.
2. **Eliminate the interface and use an abstract class.** This does NOT seem like it follows good design patterns, but would guarantee that each extending class would have the appropriate methods and even have consistent implementation until a given method is overridden.
3. **Leave As-Is.** It's possible I'm overthinking this and this really is an OK way to do it.
4. **Something Else.** I'm sure I have missed something. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you are coming from a C# perspective, that is the case, yes. I have had this problem in both Java and C#, and Java naming conventions do not call for the `I` prefix. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: I tried to simplify this question for the sake of the website, when in reality it is a much more complicated class. The idea behind this is that the `draw()` method is different based on color, but ultimately the `erase()` method just removes the color from the page in this example.

Comment: Sorry about that, have had the problem in multiple languages, but I removed the tag for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are now just asking with regards to Java, there is a third option for you, available with Java 8: [default methods on interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html).

This allows you to use an interface and define the default behaviour for `erase`, removing the need for the abstract class:

```
interface EraseableColoredPencil {

    void draw();

    default void erase() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

4. **Something else:** Follow the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/interface-segregation-principle.html) and split the interface:

   ```
   interface Drawer{
     void draw();
   }

   interface Erasable {
     void erase();
   }

   interface EraseableDrawer extends Drawer, Erasable {
   }
   ```

   Now you only need to depend on either `Drawer` or `Erasable`, depending on what method you really need (or on `ErasableDrawer` if you need both).

   If `erase()` is really the same implementation for all or most classes, you still can use an abstract class `AbstractErasableDrawer` that implements `ErasableDrawer` with a concrete implementation of `erase()` (or use a default implementation [as suggested above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31453766/664108))